# SCSS syntax errors in PHPStorm after SASS 3.3 update

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I updated my SASS to version 3.3 to take advantage of the `@each` multiple assignments. Everything worked beautifully in WebStorm - the scss file compiled with no errors and WebStorm learned the new syntax immediately. Now, the same procedure (`gem update sass`) cannot get PHPStorm at another location to learn the new syntax.

Given a list as in:

```
@each $plan, $from, $to in (economy, #7cb63d, #219242),
          (premium, #ffc631, #f79c31),
          (platinum, #f49f4c, #e86a20) {

// ...do something
}
```

PHPStorm 7.1.3 complains at the first comma. The file compiles but the syntax errors are quite annoying. Is there a way (except reboots, which I did a couple of times) to force-teach PHPStorm the new syntax?

Comment: PhpStorm version used?

Comment: 7.1.3 - updated my post to reflect that. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SASS 3.3.* support is included in PHPStorm 8. Please try the EAP version - http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program